# Array of Struct failing at the last index

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
struct student
{
     int id;
     char name[30];
     float percentage;
};

int main()
{
     int i;
     struct student record[2];

     // 1st student's record
     record[0].id=1;
     strcpy(record[0].name, "Raju");
     record[0].percentage = 86.5;

     // 2nd student's record
     record[1].id=2;
     strcpy(record[1].name, "Surendren");
     record[1].percentage = 90.5;

     // 3rd student's record
     record[2].id=3;

     //strcpy(record[2].name, "Thiyagu");//--->Bug in this line

     //record[2].percentage = 81.5;//--->Bug in this line


     for(i=0; i<3; i++)
     {
         printf("     Records of STUDENT : %d \n", i+1);
         printf(" Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
         printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
         printf(" Percentage is: %f\n\n",record[i].percentage);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I am having a difficult time debugging this code. For some reason the lines that I marked(-->) breaks the code. Right now this line and the one underneath are commented out because the code doesn't execute with them.  I have a feeling it has to do something with the null terminator.

Comment: You are putting three items into an array of two items (i.e 0, 1, 2). Computers start counting at zero

Comment: Like what Ed said, there is no record[2].

Comment: I know that they start at 0. The array size is record[2] which means it has 0,1, 2!

Comment: `struct student record[2];` You know this creates array of size 2, don't you? Its capacity is 2 structures, not the indexing stops at 2.

Comment: I can insert id of record[2]; Please read the code

Comment: C gives you enough rope to hang most of the town you live in

Comment: @RT89 yes you can even do `record[200000];` with a undefined behavior, something compiles doesn't mean its correct

Comment: Guys I am new at C. Sorry this is a newly mistake, and thanks for explaining

Answer (score 6):

`struct student record[2];` means that the array has `2` entries. The valid indices are `0` and `1`.

Trying to access `record[2]` causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).

Comment: I thought record[2] worked as 0,1,2. I change it to 3 and works fine. Thanks